# Java IDE Idea log loop

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I had just changed My IDE from Eclipse To Idea 14 ,and find a log loop problem.

I can't post image,here is the link:
 http://img.rehulu.com/idea.png

Just like the picture,keep looping about half a second and there is no income request.

The same code in Eclipse is OK.

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.rehulu.coreapi.service.impl.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

LoggingFilter.class

```
public class LoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class);
private AtomicLong id = new AtomicLong(1);
private static final String REQUEST_PREFIX = "Req:%s sId:%s Ip:%s Method:%s Uri:%s Parameter:%s";
private static final String RESPONSE_PREFIX = "Resp:";

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    long requestId = id.incrementAndGet();
    request = new RequestWrapper(requestId, request);
    response = new ResponseWrapper(requestId, response);
    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        logRequest(request);
        logResponse((ResponseWrapper) response);
    }
}

private void logRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    msg.append(REQUEST_PREFIX);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    String id = "";
    if (session != null) {
        id = session.getId();
    }

    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    String method = request.getMethod();
    String parameter = "";
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest && !isMultipart(request)) {
        HttpServletRequest requestWrapper = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Map<String, String[]> parameters = requestWrapper.getParameterMap();
        for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            String[] value = entry.getValue();
            String keyV = "";
            if (value == null || value.length == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                if (value.length == 1) {
                    keyV = value[0];
                } else {
                    keyV = Arrays.toString(value);
                }
            }
            parameter += "{" + entry.getKey() + ":" + keyV + "}";
        }
    }
    logger.info(String.format(REQUEST_PREFIX, String.valueOf(((RequestWrapper) request).getId()), id,
            IPUtil.getClientIP(request), method, uri, parameter));
}

private boolean isMultipart(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().startsWith("multipart/form-data");
}

private void logResponse(final ResponseWrapper response) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    msg.append(RESPONSE_PREFIX).append((response.getId()));
    try {
        String contentType = response.getContentType();
        if (contentType != null && contentType.contains("json")) {
            msg.append(" Payload:").append(new String(response.toByteArray(), response.getCharacterEncoding()));
        } else {
            msg.append(" Content-Type:").append(contentType);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        logger.warn("Failed to parse response payload", e);
    }
    logger.info(msg.toString());
}
```

}

Thanks very much !!!

Comment: something is hitting your app with requests ...

Comment: I run the server localhost ,the log keep going even I shut down the network connection

Comment: that doesn't make sense, if the server is local a network conneciton is not needed anyway. Your ide, or brwoser is probably making a request to your deployed app - ajax ?

Comment: thank you NimChimpsky. I checked again,and quit all browser,problem still. There is no problem when running with eclipse . It's a little weird.....

Comment: Hi,NimChimpsky ,I found the problem .
There is an open browser option in debug configurations .I think the idea will open an browser if this option checked.
But I can't find the browser any where....
Thank you so much,you are right!